# Login Authentication with simplejwt in Django Rest Framework with templates and ajax

Tags: django, ajax, rest, authentication, jwt

I am trying to make an application with Django Rest Framework and template without using any front-end application. I created the login form and user list by following this documentation https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/. It works fine when submitting forms and showing list with templates. But when I am trying to authenticate login with **simplejwt** from the browser, the authentication fails. [Failed Authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3R7rT.png)

Then I looked around and found this documentation https://ilovedjango.com/django/rest-api-framework/authentication/tips/working-example-of-jwt-authentication-with-ajax-django-rest-framework/ .
I can use the **ajax** post call to get the token and set it to local storage on submit and set the header of another API later from the local storage, but in that case, it is not going to the **action="{% url 'user:user-list-list' %}"** of the form in the template after submit. So it stays on the login page and hits only the token/ URL for the token. When I add
**location.href = "{% url 'user:user-list-list' %}"** in the ajax success, it loads the user_list but says 401 unauthorized.

Here is my user_login.html template:

```
{% load rest_framework %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>User Login</h1>

<form action="{% url 'user:user-list-list' %}" method="POST" id="login">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group ">

        <label>Username</label>


        <input id="username" name="username" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" value="">


    </div>
    <div class="form-group ">

        <label>Password</label>


        <input id="password" name="password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" value="">


    </div>


    <input type="submit" value="Login" id="submit">
</form>
</body>

<script>
    $("#login").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('username', $('#username').val().trim());
        formData.append('password', $('#password').val().trim());

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:8008/token/",
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (data) {
                // store tokens in localStorage
                window.localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', data['refresh']);
                window.localStorage.setItem('accessToken', data['access']);
            },
            error: function (rs, e) {
                console.error(rs.status);
                console.error(rs.responseText);
            }
        }); // end ajax
    });
</script>

</html>
```

Here is my login in views.py:

```
# ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
# @DESC            USER LOGIN
# @ROUTE           POST api/login/
# @ACCESS          Public
# ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class UserLoginView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'user_login.html'
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = UserLoginSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        username = request.data['username']
        password = request.data['password']

        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

            response = {}
            if user.is_active == 1 or user.is_active == True:
                response = {
                    'success': 'True',
                    'statuscode': status.HTTP_200_OK,
                    'status': 'Active',
                    'message': 'User login successful',
                    'token': serializer.data['token'],
                    'error': ''
                }
            elif user.is_active == 2:
                response = {
                    'success': 'True',
                    'statuscode': status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                    'status': 'Blocked',
                    'message': 'User has been blocked',
                    'error': ''
                }
            elif user.is_active == 3:
                response = {
                    'success': 'True',
                    'statuscode': status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                    'status': 'Unverified',
                    'message': 'Please verify your email to login!',
                    'error': ''
                }
            mylog.info(request.data)
            Log.objects.create(
                user_id=user.id,
                date_time=datetime.now(),
                login_date=datetime.now(),
                component='LoginUser',
                ip=request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
                # ip=request.META.get('HTTP_X_REAL_IP')
            )

            status_code = status.HTTP_200_OK

            return Response(response, status=status_code)

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            response = {
                'success': False,
                'statuscode': status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                'message': 'Invalid username or password',
                'error': str(e)
            }
            return Response(response)

    def list(self, request):

        try:
            serializer = UserLoginFormSerializer()
            return Response({'serializer': serializer.data})

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            response = {
                'success': False,
                'error': str(e)
            }
            return Response(response)
```

Here is my user list in views.py:

```
# /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
# @DESC            USER LIST, USER GET, USER UPDATE
# @ROUTE           GET api/userlist/, GET api/userlist/pk/, PUT api/userlist/pk/
# @ACCESS          Authenticated User
# /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class UserListView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'user_list.html'
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        users = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
        try:

            response = {
                'success': True,
                'statuscode': status.HTTP_200_OK,
                'data': serializer.data,
                'message': "View users Successful"
            }

            return Response({'response': response})

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            response = {
                'success': False,
                'statuscode': status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                'message': 'User list fetch error',
                'menu': 0,
                'error': str(e)
            }
            mylog.error(e)
            return Response(response)
```

I understand that I need to somehow get the token in the header of the user list API for the authentication to work, but I can't seem to find a way. Is this anyhow possible?

According to the documentation, I added this code in the script of user_list.html, but didn't work as the API is not authenticated for the user.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '{% url 'user:user-list-list' %}',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${window.localStorage.getItem('accessToken')}`
            },
            type: "GET",
            tokenFlag: true,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: handleAjaxError
        });

    });

    function handleAjaxError(rs, e) {
        /*
            And if it returns 401, then we call obtainAccessTokenWithRefreshToken() method
            To get a new access token using refresh token.
        */
        if (rs.status == 401) {
            if (this.tokenFlag) {
                this.tokenFlag = false;
                if (obtainAccessTokenWithRefreshToken()) {
                    this.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${window.localStorage.getItem('accessToken')}`
                    $.ajax(this);  // calling API endpoint again with new access token
                }
            }
        } else {
            console.error(rs.responseText);
        }
    }

    function obtainAccessTokenWithRefreshToken() {
        /*
            This method will create new access token by using refresh token.
            If refresh token is invalid it will redirect user to login page
        */
        let flag = true;
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('refresh', window.localStorage.getItem('refreshToken'));
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8008/token/refresh/',
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (data) {
                window.localStorage.setItem('accessToken', data['access']);
            },
            error: function (rs, e) {
                if (rs.status == 401) {
                    flag = false;
                    window.location.href = "/user/login/";
                } else {
                    console.error(rs.responseText);
                }
            }
        }); // end ajax
        return flag
    }
```

How can I authenticate the user and render all other Rest APIs with authenticated users in this approach?

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you have is you are mixing sessionStorage and localStorage.

In login.html jQuery code, you are using localStorage to store a accessToke and refreshToken

```
// store tokens in localStorage
localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', data['refresh']);
localStorage.setItem('accessToken', data['access']);
```

And in the list_users.html, you are trying to access the token with
`sessionStorage`

Change this code which is return `accessToken null`

```
headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer 
           ${window.sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken')}` // accessToken is null
            },
```

To be this

```
headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer 
           ${localStorage.getItem('accessToken')}`
            },
```

Now you have access to the accessToken stored in localStorage.

Comment: I did that before then I tried to use sessionstorage but forgot to change the code here. That doesn't work either as my django view is not even letting me get inside it, let alone the template. I am confused how to call my API with the header from the login template.

Comment: Have you checked the access token is being returned and stored in local storage?

Comment: yes it is stored there. But my API needs it on its header. The problem is that the template which includes the script to add it to header, is not loaded because of the authorization of the view.

Comment: Hey the code looks fine, I think using `window.localStorage` is the problem here, instead, try to use `localStorage.getItem()` try it and see if it works and also make sure CORS middleware is set in settings.py. Thanks